# More Pythonic way of writing If-Else-Pass

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have this function that cleans my input tables (since I have multiple tables that need this treatment, I decided to write this function).

The parameter 'table' is our input pandas DataFrame while 'control_list' is just a verification whether we want to perform the transformation.

```
def input_formatting(table, control_list):
    #drop rows with NA's
    if control_list[0] == 1:
        table.dropna(inplace = True, how = 'all')
    else:
        pass
    #change all column names to lower case
    if control_list[1] == 1:
        table.columns = table.columns.str.lower()
    else:
        pass
    #remove all whitespace in column names
    if control_list[2] == 1:
        table.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip(), inplace = True)
    else:
        pass
    #change all spaces to _ in col names
    if control_list[3] == 1:
        table.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace(' ','_'), inplace = True)
    else:
        pass
```

Example of using this would be:

```
input_formatting(some_df, [1,1,1,1])
```

**My question is, can someone recommend a more Pythonic / elegant way of writing the if-else-pass statement?** It seems unnecessarily verbose and long.

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the ```else``` it is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`else` is optional in if-else i.e.:

```
if True:
   print("True")
else:
   pass
```

might be written in more concise way as

```
if True:
   print("True")
```

`help("if")` does says

```
The "if" statement
******************

The "if" statement is used for conditional execution:

   if_stmt ::= "if" expression ":" suite
               ("elif" expression ":" suite)*
               ["else" ":" suite]

It selects exactly one of the suites by evaluating the expressions one
by one until one is found to be true (see section Boolean operations
for the definition of true and false); then that suite is executed
(and no other part of the "if" statement is executed or evaluated).
If all expressions are false, the suite of the "else" clause, if
present, is executed.

Related help topics: TRUTHVALUE
```

Note *if present* in last sentence.

Comment: Thanks, this makes it obvious!